# Como fazer para uma pagina não bugar quando o navegador for redimensionado?

Tags: css, css3

Bem, eu desenvolvi um site para um trabalho da escola, o problema é que quando eu redimensiono o navegador, o site fica todo bugado, os elementos saem de suas posições originais e o site fica impossível de se mexer. Eu queria saber como faço para arrumar isso.

**Site normal:**

[image: Normal]

**Site bugado:**

[image: Bugado]

Comment: Estou dando um voto de fechamento pois a pergunta é vaga demais para que se possa dizer qual é a causa do problema. Se você quiser elaborar mais (apesar de já ter aceito uma resposta), acredito que o conteúdo possa ser mais útil para futuros visitantes do site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta você utilizar os [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) para todos os elementos e fazer com que se adaptem corretamente à dimensão do navegador.

Utilizar o [Grid CSS](http://960.gs/) ou mesmo o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) que também tem suporte a grids é uma boa, pois ai você já faz um layout adaptável.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode também definir uma largura mínima para o seu site através do CSS `min-width: 1000px`.

Para saber mais sobre essa definição: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Answer (score 1):

Você já viu o [Twitter BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? é um conjunto de classes CSS que você pode utilizar para que seu site fique responsivo, ou seja, você pode utiliza-lo em varias dimensões e ele se adaptará a resolução do dispositivo.

da uma conferida, lá tem um breve tutorial ensinando como utilizar as classes CSS.

Comment: ok, vou dar uma olhada. :)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o layout HTML não está formatado para ser *responsive*.

Podes usar vários sistemas de CSS grid para resolver esse problema.

http://getbootstrap.com/

http://960.gs/

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho a você usar algum 'framework' css, como por exemplo o bootstrap ou foundation... São ótimos para desenvolvimento de paginas responsivas, com rapidez e sem dor de cabeça.

Comment: Você poderia elaborar mais? Conselhos do que usar não são considerados boas respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Posso até estar enganado, mas pelo que parece, você deve estar começando a trabalhar com html/css. Se o site que você mostrou aqui tiver sido feito com tabelas (o que semanticamente não é recomendável), sugiro que você use medidas absolutas em pixels na largura e altura das células, ao invés de medidas relativas (porcentagem, em e etc). Tente usar largura fixa para a tabela ou container principal e vá acomodando os elementos com as larguras também delimitadas.

Seria interessante você usar algum tipo de CSS Reset.

As recomendações postadas pelos amigos aqui são muito válidas, porém, a curva de aprendizagem e domínio da maioria deles é bem longa. Te aconselho a estudar mais o desenvolvimento tableless usando o HTML e o CSS para só depois partir para o uso de frameworks. Só com isso você já terá um longo trabalho pela frente.